# Ship gsl as a 3rd party dynamic library with a Debian package generated with CPack

Tags: cmake, cpack

I have a CMake project which depends on `gsl >= 2.3` for which I would like to distribute a debian package on `ubuntu/xenial`. As `gsl > 2.3` is not the version shipped with `ubuntu/xenial`, I can not use in that case the `CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_SHLIBDEPS` variable to set `gsl` as a dependency of my package. Thus, I would like to ship the `libgsl` and `libgslcblas` dynamic libraries, that I built on my own, with my debian package. I tried the following approach

```
find_package(GSL 2.3 REQUIRED) --> this return the ${GSL_LIBRARIES} variable
...
install(FILES ${GSL_LIBRARIES} DESTINATION ${DEBIAN_INSTALL_DIR}lib COMPONENT LIB)
```

but because `GSL_LIBRARIES` returns links to the targeted libraries, it installed the links and not the libraries. Would you know how to proceed ?

Comment: "I tried with a CMake `install(FILES...)` command but it installed the link to the actual library instead of the library itself." - Probably, the link to the library is what you actually pass to the `install` command.

Comment: yes, exactly and this is where I am in trouble

Comment: So, just pass actual library file to the `install(FILES)` command, not a link to it. What is a problem in that?

Comment: the `${GSL_LIBRARIES}` variable  returned by the `find_package(GSL 2.3 REQUIRED)` call, that I use to feed the `install` command, returns the link path instead of the actual targeted libraries

Comment: Oh, so you tried to install libraries listed in the variable `GSL_LIBRARIES`, which is created by `find_package`. Can you add this into the question post? I thought you install files manually. As for the problem - you may try to resolve paths listed in the variable. Use `readlink -f` shell's command for do that.

Comment: I can give a try even if I wanted to avoid this kind of system call which may indicate that I am thinking wrong and that my approach is not the way to go

Comment: Yes, `find_package()` is intended for **use** (link with) the library, not for **installing** it. For proper installing a 3d party lbrary you need to use an installer of the library's itself. The whole attempt to installing the 3d party manually is not a proper way. However, there many things in programming which are not intended to work, but needed. If you you need to install 3d-party library without the library's installer - just do that.

Comment: you right. thanks for your help